# What are the differences between instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) vs ViewController(nibName:bundle:)?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to understand communication between two view controllers.

When passing data without segue, I saw two methods to create destination controller instance.

First one is `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`. Second one is `ViewController(nibName:bundle:)`. Then present them with `present(UIViewController..)`.

What are the differences between the two methods? Are they just to find view controllers by a storyboard identifier or a `nibName`?

Comment: Yes, it depends on where (i.e. in which kind of file) the view controller has been designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier)` is for view controllers that are **inside a storyboard**, while `UIViewController(nibName:bundle:)` is for ones that **were created in a `.xib` file**. Both can be used, it just depends on the method the application was created.

If you are planning to make complex view controller relationships, storyboards might be the better solution for you, since view controller organization is more efficient when you can structure your VCs in a two-dimensional place.